# Pagination not working with next page button in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, screen-scraping

I have a problem with the booking reviews next page, sometimes it works while other times it doesn't.
For example, it works fine for the first 4 pages (out of 50) and stops on page 4 without continuing to page 5.
Other times, with a different link it proceeds for 5 out of 5 pages.

What could it depend on?

All my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as     EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'it_IT.UTF-8')
os.environ["LC_ALL"] = "C.UTF-8"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

all_dates=[]
hotels_link = []
hotels_city = []
all_cities = []
all_reviews = []


def extract_reviews():
    try:
        with open("my_link_file.txt", 'r', encoding='UTF-8')     as links_file:
            for line in links_file.readlines():
                try:
                    link, città, posizione =     line.strip().split(',')
                print("Link:", link)
                print("Città:", città)
                print("Posizione:", posizione)


                try:
                    driver.get(link)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Errore durante il caricamento del link {link}: {str(e)}")
                    continue

                try:
                    cookies = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()
                except:
                    pass
                time.sleep(2)
                try:
                    recenti = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="review_sort"]/option[2]').click()
                except:
                    pass

                current_page = 1

                time.sleep(2)
                while True:
                    try:
                        last_page = int(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="review_list_page_container"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/a/span[1]').text)
                        print(last_page)
                    except NoSuchElementException:
                        last_page = 1

                    review_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                            ('xpath', '//div[@class="bui-grid__column-9 c-review-block__right"]')))

                    for review_element in review_elements:
                        date_text = review_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                                'span.c-review-block__date').text.replace(
                            "Recensione: ", "")

                        # Gestisci date vuote o in formato non valido
                        try:
                            date = datetime.strptime(date_text, "%d %B %Y")
                        except ValueError:
                            date = None

                        review_text_parts = review_element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.c-review__body')
                        review_texts = [part.text.strip() for part in review_text_parts]

                        if "Il cliente non ha lasciato un commento" in review_texts:
                            continue

                        if date and datetime(2021, 1, 6) <= date <= datetime(2023, 9, 30):
                            review_texts = [text for text in review_texts if text]  # Rimuovi testi vuoti

                            if review_texts:
                                for review_text in review_texts:
                                    all_reviews.append({'Data': date_text, 'Recensione': review_text, 'Città': città, 'Link':link})

                                    # Stampa per il debug
                                    print("Data:", date_text)
                                    print("Recensione:", review_text)
                                    print("Città:", città)
                                    print("-" * 50)  # Linea divisoria tra le recensioni

                    current_page += 1

                    if current_page > last_page:
                        break

                    next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located(
                            (By.XPATH, '//a[@class="pagenext"]')))

                    try:
                        next_button.click()
                    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
                        print("Elemento intercettato. Passaggio al prossimo link.")
                        break
                    except TimeoutException:
                        print("Timeout durante il clic su 'pagina successiva'. Passaggio al prossimo link.")
                        break

                    time.sleep(5)

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Errore generico con il link {link}: {str(e)}")
                continue  # Passa al link successivo se si verifica un errore

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Errore generico: {str(e)}")

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(all_reviews)

df.to_csv('my_file_reviews.csv', index=False, header = True)
extract_reviews()
```